# Effect of fetchsize and batchsize on Spark

Tags: database, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to control the reading and writing speed to an RDB by **Spark** directly, yet the related parameters as the title already revealed seemingly were not working.

Can I conclude that `fetchsize` and `batchsize` didn't work with my testing method? Or they do affect on the facet of reading and writing since the measure result is reasonable based on scale.

### Stats of `betchsize`, `fetchsize` and data set

```
/*Dataset*/
+--------------+-----------+
| Observations | Dataframe |
+--------------+-----------+
|      109,077 | Initial   |
|      345,732 | Ultimate  |
+--------------+-----------+
/*fetchsize*/
+-----------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| fetchsize | batchsize | Reading Time(ms) | Writing Time(ms) |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
|        10 |        10 |            2,103 |           38,428 |
|       100 |        10 |            2,123 |           38,021 |
|     1,000 |        10 |            2,032 |           38,345 |
|    10,000 |        10 |            2,016 |           37,892 |
|    50,000 |        10 |            2,017 |           37,795 |
|   100,000 |        10 |            2,055 |           38,720 |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
/*batchsize*/
+-----------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| fetchsize | batchsize | Reading Time(ms) | Writing Time(ms) |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
|        10 |        10 |            2,072 |           37,977 |
|        10 |       100 |            2,077 |           36,990 |
|        10 |     1,000 |            2,034 |           36,703 |
|        10 |    10,000 |            1,979 |           36,980 |
|        10 |    50,000 |            2,043 |           36,749 |
|        10 |   100,000 |            2,005 |           36,624 |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
```

## Measures watched from **Datadog**

[image: MySQL performance measures]

### Detail that may be helpful

I created two **m4.xlarge** Linux entities on **AWS**, one is for the execution of **Spark**, the other is for data storage on an RDB, using **Datadog** to watch the performance of the **Spark** application, especially on the reading and writing to the RDB. **Spark** was in the standalone mode, and the application for test is simply pulling some data from a **MySQL** RDB, doing some computation, then pushing back to the **MySQL**.

Some details are as the following:

1. JDBC properties are put in a file, **application.conf**, like the following:

   ```
   spark {
     Reading {
       url: "jdbc:mysql://address/designated database"
       driver: "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
       user: "username"
       password: "password"
       fetchsize: "10000"
     }
     Writing {
       url: "jdbc:mysql://address/designated database"
       driver: "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
       dbtable: "designated table"
       user: "username"
       password: "password"
       batchsize: "10000"
       truncate: "true"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Logging while executing the application is enabled by **log4jx2**, within it, time for writing is measured.

   ```
                   .
                   .
                   .
   startTime = System.nanoTime()
   val connection = new Properties()
   configureProperties(connection, conf, "spark.Writing")
   val ultimateObservations = ultimateResult.count()
   ultimateResult.write
       .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
       .jdbc(conf.getString("spark.Writing.url"),
             conf.getString("spark.Writing.dbtable"),
             connection)
   finishedTime = System.nanoTime()
   logger.info("Finished writing from Spark to MySQL, taking {} milliseconds; approximately {} rows/s",
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert((finishedTime - startTime), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS),
         ultimateObservations/TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert((finishedTime - startTime), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
       )
                   .
                   .
                   .

   /*
    *configureProperties is a customized function
    */
   def configureProperties(connectionEntity: Properties, conf: Config, designatedString: String): Unit = {
       val propertiesCarrier = conf.getConfig(designatedString)
       for (entry <- propertiesCarrier.entrySet) {
         if (entry.getKey().trim() != "url" && entry.getKey().trim() != "dbtable") {
           connectionEntity.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().unwrapped().toString())
           logger.info("Database configuration: ({}, {}).",
     entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().unwrapped().toString: Any)
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: **@Scott Hsieh** were you able to determine whether or not `fetchsize` and `batchsize` have any perceptible impact? I'm also trying the same thing (only `fetchsize`) and my results thus far conform with yours, i.e., `fetchsize` doesn't seem to have any *perceptible* impact.

Comment: @y2k-shubham I can only conclude these two parameters, i.e., `fetchsize` and `batchsize` will have palpable impact if the size of data is larger. I didn't conduct further experiment, but used an additional step to achieve my original goal of controlling the reading and writing speeds for RDBs.

Comment: Can you shed some light on the `"additional step"`? I have to read complete `MySQL` tables (several tables, total about 600G data) into `Spark` `DataFrame`s and even though I'm *parallelizing* the *read task* using `DataFrameReader.jdbc(..numPartitions..)`, I could still help from increased reading speed from RDB